# Formulating mathematical model that minimizes the largest deviation between the data and the line

Tags: mathematical-modeling, least-squares

Can someone help me and explain all the steps of solving this problem which is in the field of Model Fitting and Least-Squares Fit. Thank you.

PROBLEM:  For each of the following data sets, formulate the mathematical model that minimizes the largest deviation between the data and the line y = ax+b. If a computer is available, solve for the estimates of a and b.

x: 1.0 ,  2.3 ,  3.7  , 4.2 ,  6.1 ,  7.0.

y: 3.6  , 3.0 , 3.2  ,  5.1  , 5.3  , 6.8.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are being asked to minimize the largest difference between the data point and its estimate, *not* the sum of squared differences?

Comment: $\min_{a,b} F(a,b)$, where $F(a,b) = \max_i |ax_i+b - y_i|$. Please show us your thoughts. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Set up a spreadsheet and try different values of $a$ and $b$. Start with arbitrary values, then search for the best $a$, then search for the best $b$, then search for $a$ again until you see that nothing improves. It takes no more than 5 minutes.

Comment: @kccu This is the solution from the book, but I do not quite get it. ->  min r =0.92; a = 0.533333; b = 2.14667.
The least-squares fit to this data set gives the
line y  = 0.564 x + 2.21 with d max = 1.0

Comment: @HansEngler I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: @HansEngler A First Course in Mathematical Modeling (Frank R. Giordano, William P. Fox, Steven B. Horton, Maurice D. Weir). This problem is from Section 3.2.